# Can psyllium husk be used as gelatin for jello?

Tags: substitutions, gelatin

I need to make jello. Would psyllium husk work as a jello replacement?

Comment: why do you want to replace gelatin?

Answer (score 2):

Psyllium husk is a good source of soluble fiber, but it's not a very good stabilizer or a gelling agent.

If you want to replace gelatin inn recipes there's [plenty of great vegan substitutes](https://www.goodfoodfun.com/gelatin-substitute/). I'd recommend using agar-agar instead; it's the closest gelling agent but it's stronger, so you need to use less than you're used to.

Comment: Just a note - agar-agar produces a more crisp breakable gel, not quite as rubbery as gelatin. The sort of gel you find in bubble tea/boba.

Comment: @bob1 yep it's not gonna be exactly the same